# How to make "Search FIlter" Searches in the new Created Elements By the "innerHTML" code?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a website that allows the user to create a contact, and there is a search box that allows the user to search in the created contacts.

The problem is when the user creates contact and searches, the search box does not work.

The code is running well when I create the contacts manually in the HTML file. It means that the search box only searches in the HTML file, and doesn't search in the newly created contacts by the innerHTML code by JavaScript.

And please answer me with JAVASCRIPT code, not jQuery.

This is my code, only HTML and JAVASCRIPT , no css :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Javascript Project 11</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="myForm">
         <input id="create" type="text" placeholder="create">
         <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <br>
      <input id="search" placeholder="search..." type="text">
      <div id="demo">
         <!--HERE IS YOUR LIST OF CONTACTS-->
         <ul id="names">
         </ul>
      </div>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
//CREATE NEW CONTACT 
//CREATE NEW LI I MEAN

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', createContact)

function createContact(e) {
        //input
        var menuItem = document.getElementById('menuItem');

        var newName = document.getElementById('create').value;
        var demo = document.getElementById('demo');

        demo.innerHTML +=
            '<li class=menuItem><a href="#">' + newName + '</a></li>';

        e.preventDefault();
}

//Search Filter
var searchBox = document.getElementById('search');
searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', filter);

function filter() {
        var ul = document.getElementById('names');

        var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.menuItem');

        var searchBoxValue = document.getElementById('search').value.toUpperCase();

        for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            var newName = document.getElementById('create').value;
            var a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchBoxValue) > -1) {

                li[i].style.display = '';

            }
            else {
                li[i].style.display = 'none';
            }

        }
    }

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <title>Javascript Project 11</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       </head>
       <body>
          <form id="myForm">
             <input id="create" type="text" placeholder="create">
             <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <br>
          <input id="search" placeholder="search..." type="text">
          <div id="demo">
             <!--HERE IS YOUR LIST OF CONTACTS-->
             <ul id="names">
             </ul>
          </div>
          <script src="js/main.js"></script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You could create special variable with the list of your contracts. It will be an array of objects(if there should be multiple properties) or just strings(names of contracts). Then you can just make function that will push new contracts into existing array and another function that updates that user sees. And make filter over that array. Moreover, there is a Array.prototype.filter method that can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append new items to `<div id="demo">` instead of `<ul id="names">`. It should be like this:

```
var names = document.getElementById('names');
names.innerHTML += '<li class="menuItem"><a href="#">' + newName + '</a></li>';
```

```js
//CREATE NEW CONTACT 
    //CREATE NEW LI I MEAN


    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', craeteContact)
    
    function craeteContact(e) {
    
        //input
        var menuItem = document.getElementById('menuItem');
    
    
        var newName = document.getElementById('create').value;
        var names= document.getElementById('names');
    
        names.innerHTML +=
            '<li class="menuItem"><a href="#">' + newName + '</a></li>';
    
        e.preventDefault();
    
    }
    

       //Search Filter
    
    var searchBox = document.getElementById('search');
    searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', filter);
    
    
    function filter() {
    
        var ul = document.getElementById('names');
    
        var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.menuItem');
    
    
        var searchBoxValue = document.getElementById('search').value.toUpperCase();
    
        for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            var newName = document.getElementById('create').value;
            var a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchBoxValue) > -1) {
    
                li[i].style.display = '';
    
            }
            else {
                li[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
    
        }
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <title>Javascript Project 11</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       </head>
       <body>
          <form id="myForm">
             <input id="create" type="text" placeholder="create">
             <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <br>
          <input id="search" placeholder="search..." type="text">
          <div id="demo">
             <!--HERE IS YOUR LIST OF CONTACTS-->
             <ul id="names">
             </ul>
          </div>
          <script src="js/main.js"></script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Quotes are optional in this case.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you place `li` elements in `#demo` instead of `#names`

you should use `console.log()` to debug

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to save names and then search the array. why you get data from UI everytime

```js
var searchBox = document.getElementById('search');
searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', filter);
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', craeteContact)

var names = [];

function craeteContact(e) {
    var menuItem = document.getElementById('menuItem');
    var newName = document.getElementById('create').value;
    var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    
    names.push(newName.toUpperCase()); // add new name to array
    
    demo.innerHTML += '<li class=menuItem><a href="#">' + newName + '</a></li>';
    e.preventDefault();
}



function filter() {
    var searchValue = searchBox.value.toUpperCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (names[i].indexOf(searchValue) > -1) {
          console.log("found");
        }
        else {
          console.log("not found");
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <title>Javascript Project 11</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       </head>
       <body>
          <form id="myForm">
             <input id="create" type="text" placeholder="create">
             <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <br>
          <input id="search" placeholder="search..." type="text">
          <div id="demo">
             <!--HERE IS YOUR LIST OF CONTACTS-->
             <ul id="names">
             </ul>
          </div>
          <script src="js/main.js"></script>
       </body>
    </html>
```